# undefined method `mount_uploaders' when using carrierwave multiple uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using carrierwave for multiple uploads. 
In this process I added 
**gem 'carrierwave'** in Gemfile

```
rails g migration add_avatars_to_users avatars:json
rake db:migrate
```

In my model:

```
class InvoiceDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploaders :avatars, AvatarUploaderz
end
```

form:

```
<%= form_for(@invoice_detail , html: {class: 'form-horizontal', role: 'form' }) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :invoice_date, :class => 'control-label' %>
                <div class="controls1">

    <%= f.date_select :invoice_date, :class => 'text_area' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= form.file_field :files, multiple: true %>

     <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :avatar, :multiple => true , :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.file_field :avatar, :class => 'file_field', :required => true %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%end%>
<%end%>
```

when I run the server, I am getting error as

*undefined method `mount_uploaders' for #*

With some googling I added require `'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'`
in my model, but it didn't helped me. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your gem version
Please go through this hope this will help you.

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1551

**EDIT**:
checkout this line
  **mount_uploaders :avatars, AvatarUploaderz**

it should be
  **mount_uploaders :avatars, AvatarUploader**

Comment: I checked with the version, it is '0.10.0' the latest version.

Comment: If carrier wave carrierwave (0.10.0), try to use 'mount_uploader' other than 'mount_uploaders'

Comment: It is for multiple uploads. So I used mount_uploaders with reference to [link](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)